# Aligning side-by-side related plots with ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, gridextra

I have the following two-part plot which are not aligned:

[image]

[Side-by-side plots not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVfDf.png)

These plots are produced by the following code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra) 

set.seed(0)
data <- data.frame(x=rpois(30,5),y=rpois(30,11),z=rpois(300,25))
left.plot   <- ggplot(data,aes(x,y)) 
               + geom_bin2d(binwidth=1)

margin.data <- as.data.frame( margin.table(table(data),1))
right.plot  <- ggplot(margin.data, aes(x=x,y=Freq))
               + geom_bar(stat="identity")+coord_flip()                                                        

grid.arrange(left.plot, right.plot, ncol=2)
```

How can I align the rows in the left plot to the bars in the right plot?

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are simple, albeit twofold.

Ultimately you need to use `scale_y_continuous()` and `scale_x_continuous()` to set your axis limits to match on eatch figure. That's impeded by the fact that the `x` value is a factor. Convert it to a numeric and throw in some scaling and you're good to go.

```
left.plot   <- ggplot(data,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_bin2d(binwidth=1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 16))

margin.data <- as.data.frame( margin.table(table(data),1))
right.plot  <- ggplot(margin.data, aes(x=as.numeric(as.character(x)),y=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 16)) + 
  xlab("x") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand why in your solution in the right plot there are 3 bars in the level 4 or less while in the left there is only in marking below 4.

Comment: It looks like our random data are different; try my adjustments on your machine and verify that your right and left figures align. Let me know if they don't.

Comment: No, they do not align. See it in your figure. Left plot has no data on line of value 3 while your right plot does. See the figure my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Using package ggExtra I was able to get an almost solution

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggExtra)

set.seed(0)
data <- data.frame(x=rpois(30,5),y=rpois(30,11),z=rpois(300,25))
left.plot <- ggplot(data,aes(x,y)) + geom_bin2d(binwidth=1)

ggMarginal(left.plot, margins="y", type = "histogram",  size=2,bins=(max(data$y)-min(data$y)+1),binwidth=1.06)
```

I say almost because I had to set manually binwidth=1.06 to align bar and counts.

[Manually aligned plots using ggExtra::ggMarginal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doYfe.png)